# MongoError: not authorized on local to execute command while deploy on meteor galaxy

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-galaxy, mlab

I am trying to deploy my app using meteor galaxy using below command

```
DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=us-east-1.galaxy-deploy.meteor.com meteor deploy icrm.meteorapp.com --settings scalingo.json
```

but i am getting this error

`MongoError: not authorized on local to execute command { find: "oplog.rs", filter: {}, sort: { $natural: -1 }, projection: { ts: 1 }, limit: 1 }` in logs

in my scalingo.json, i have set as follow

```
"galaxy.meteor.com": {
        "env": {
            "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://username:password@ds137100.mlab.com:37100/icrm",
            "MONGO_OPLOG_URL": "mongodb://username:password@ds137100.mlab.com:37100/local?authSource=icrm",
            "ROOT_URL": "http://icrm.meteorapp.com/"
        }
    }
```

and when i am accessing http://icrm.meteorapp.com/  i am getting

```
503 Service Unavailable: No healthy endpoints to handle the request.
```

I know i am doing some mistake in setting MONGO_OPLOG_URL, i am writing same username and password in both MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL, i am using free sandbox version, please help me to sort out this problem, if possible suggest me solution with free sandbox version...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you are using Scalingo MongoDB, you probably can just jump to #4 in my answer (this assumes that Scalingo did steps #1-3 for you).

Answer (score 6):

It certainly sounds like you have an issue with your mongodb configuration.  Unfortunately, there are a lot of differences between the various mongodb service providers, but let me share with you how mine is setup (maybe this will help you in some way).  I do want to note that I am managing my own mongodb instance from a cloud linux server (instead of using a mongodb service).

1. Enable security authorization (e.g. it is enabled in `mongod.conf`) and ensure that you have created an admin user (which you will use to create all your other users) and a user that your meteor app will use to access mongodb.

   First you must create an "admin" user with the correct roles to add new users.  From the mongo shell you can do this.

   ```
   admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
   admin.createUser(
     {
       user: "admin",
       pwd: "admin-password",
       roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
     }
   );
   ```

   Then from the shell, login as the above user and create your account used by your meteor app.  Note, I am calling my meteor app database `meteor_db` in this example.  Change this to whatever you want.

   ```
   db.getSiblingDB("admin").auth("admin", "admin-password" );

   use meteor_db;

   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "meteor",
       pwd: "meteor",
       roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "meteor_db" } ]
     }
   );
   ```
2. With that done, you need to configure mongodb to enable the oplog (which meteor will use for tailing).  To do this, you must setup replication and 1 replication set by editing `mongod.conf` and modifying the `replication` section.

   ```
   replication:
       replSetName: rs0
   ```

   Restart mongodb and then initiate replication on the new member from the mongo shell (you must do this as root).  Modify the below example with your specific hostname and port if you are not running mongodb on the default localhost and port number).

   ```
   rs.initiate({_id:"rs0", members: [{"_id":0, "host":"127.0.0.1:27017"}]});
   ```
3. Now that oplog is enabled, you must create a user that can access the oplog.  This is the user you will use to configure `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` (used by meteor).  From the mongo shell, login as the admin user (created above) and create the new `oplogger` user.

   ```
   db.getSiblingDB("admin").auth("admin", "admin-password" );

   admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");

   admin.createUser(
     {
       user: "oplogger",
       pwd: "oplogger-password",
       roles: [ { role: "read", db: "local" } ]
     }
   );
   ```
4. With all the setup done, you just need to set your meteor env variables and restart your app.

   ```
   export MONGO_URL='mongodb://meteor:meteor@<hostname>:<port>/meteor_db'
   export MONGO_OPLOG_URL='mongodb://oplogger:oplogger-password@<hostname>:<port>/local?authSource=admin'
   ```

Let me know if you run into any issue or have further question.  Also, here are some additional resources that I found helpful when I was trying to get all this setup (perhaps they will also help).

- [How to enable the oplog on Ubuntu MongoDB for Meteor](https://ianhowson.com/how-to-enable-the-oplog-on-ubuntu-mongodb-for-meteor.html)
- [Meteor OplogObserveDriver Notes](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/oplog-observe-driver.md)
- [How to add oplog tailing to meteor up (mup) on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/meteor-secret/adding-oplog-tailing-with-meteor-up-mup-and-ubuntu-efa644f397e9#.8iv6cpgah)

Comment: not helpful, i have required solution in terms of using mLab

Comment: I'm sorry that this was not helpful for you, however I saw that no one had tried to offer you any help at all, so I figured I would at least share to see if you can gleam any help from this...otherwise you would have had no replies whatsoever. Did you try using different a user for your  `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` env var? Clearly that is one big difference with what you are trying to do and what is common?  Try and think about the main concepts of my answer instead of the exact specifics to see if it helps your problem.  For example, you need a different user for `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` and `MONGO_URL`.